# CDT library and precompiled headers stdafx

Tags: c++, cmake

I have prepared the most minimal example of my code. Please download it if you could help me first. I am using a very simple CDT triangulation library that supposed to be a header only.
If I included the main header file of this library to the main.cpp everything compiles and works. If I include the "CDT.h" in my precompiled header "stdafx.h" LNK2005 error appears.

**Question:** Could you please explain how can I include "CDT.h" in the "stdafx.h" without the linking error?

My simplified project:
https://mega.nz/file/sw5HxJxY#DGGsatSFZ8od2sSKK7AMMbq23RGDSLoqNw-O0zcfhj0

Since Stackoverflow is against the 3rd party links I will share the full code below.

To run the cmake you need firstly write:

```
cmake --fresh -DGET_LIBS=ON -DBUILD_MY_PROJECTS=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 .. && cmake --build . --config Release
```

Then

```
cmake --fresh -DGET_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_MY_PROJECTS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 .. && cmake --build . --config Release
```

In the second step the linking breaks with LNK2005 error.

My CMakeLists:

```
#cmake --fresh -DGET_LIBS=ON -DBUILD_MY_PROJECTS=OFF  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release"  -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 .. && cmake --build . --config Release
#cmake --fresh -DGET_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_MY_PROJECTS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release"  -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 .. && cmake --build . --config Release

########################################################################
# PROPERTIES
########################################################################
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24.2)



project(cdt_test LANGUAGES C CXX)

set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0097 NEW)
# Set global property (all targets are impacted)
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE "${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E time")


  message(AUTHOR_WARNING "RELEASE IS BEING CONFIGURED" )
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE_INIT "Release")





########################################################################
#
# START SUPERBUILD - DOWNLOAD LIBRARIES FROM GITHUB REPOSIROTRIES
#
########################################################################
#cmake_policy(SET CMP0097 NEW)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0135 NEW)
include(ExternalProject)



SET(GET_LIBS "" CACHE STRING "Set option to download dependencies")
if (GET_LIBS)
  message(AUTHOR_WARNING "GET_LIBS_" ${GET_LIBS})
  message(AUTHOR_WARNING  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cdt/CDT")

  ########################################################################
# GLM
######################################################################## 
  ExternalProject_Add(glm
  URL https://github.com/g-truc/glm/releases/download/0.9.9.8/glm-0.9.9.8.7z
  CMAKE_ARGS
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}
    #-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install"
  SOURCE_DIR   "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/glm"
    #INSTALL_DIR   "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/install"
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND "" #do not configure
  BUILD_COMMAND "" #do not buld
  INSTALL_COMMAND "" #installer for now is empty
)


  #######################################################################
  # CDT
  ####################################################################### 
  ExternalProject_Add(cdt
      URL https://github.com/artem-ogre/CDT/archive/refs/tags/1.1.2.zip
      CMAKE_ARGS
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
        -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}
        -DCDT_USE_AS_COMPILED_LIBRARY = ON
        #-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install"
        #INSTALL_DIR   "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/install"
      SOURCE_DIR   "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cdt"
      CONFIGURE_COMMAND "" #do not configure
      BUILD_COMMAND "" #do not buld
      INSTALL_COMMAND "" #installer for now is empty
  )

endif()

SET(BUILD_MY_PROJECTS "" CACHE STRING "Build Project")
if (BUILD_MY_PROJECTS)
  message(AUTHOR_WARNING "BUILD_MY_PROJECTS_" ${BUILD_MY_PROJECTS})
  ###############################################################################
  # LINK HEADERS TO EXE
  # check path:
  # message(AUTHOR_WARNING "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/viewer/include/stb")
  ###############################################################################
  
  message(AUTHOR_WARNING "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cdt/CDT/include/")
  list(APPEND petras_include_paths 
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/"
  #glm
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/glm/"
  #cdt
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cdt/CDT/include/"
  )

  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp   ) 

  target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${petras_include_paths}>") #header for the library



  ###############################################################################
  # PCH support
  ###############################################################################
  #option(KDV_BUILD_USING_PCH "Build using pre-compile header support" ON)
  #if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL 3.16 AND KDV_BUILD_USING_PCH) # support for PCHs in CMake was added in 3.16
  message(STATUS "Compiling using pre-compiled header support")
  target_precompile_headers(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE stdafx.h) # With PUBLIC they will be used by targets using this target
  #target_precompile_headers(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE   "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build_win/CMakeFiles/compas_wood.dir/Release/cmake_pch.hxx")
  set(CMAKE_PCH_INSTANTIATE_TEMPLATES ON)
endif()
```

stdafx.h

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <map>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <numeric>
#include <limits>
#include <chrono>
#include <float.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

// glm
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/quaternion.hpp>
#include <glm/ext.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/euler_angles.hpp>

#include "CDT.h"
```

stdafx.cpp

```
#include <stdafx.h>
```

main.cpp

```
// cmake-- fresh - DGET_LIBS = ON - DBUILD_MY_PROJECTS = OFF - DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = "Release" - G "Visual Studio 17 2022" - A x64..&& cmake-- build.--config Release
// cmake-- fresh - DGET_LIBS = OFF - DBUILD_MY_PROJECTS = ON - DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = "Release" - G "Visual Studio 17 2022" - A x64..&& cmake-- build.--config Release

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CDT.h"
#include "opengl_triangulation.h"

inline void add(
    const std::vector<std::vector<glm::vec3>> &in_polylines,
    const glm::vec4 &obj_color,
    bool convex_only = false,
    double closed_tolerance = 0.001,
    float shading_w = 1,
    std::string group_name = "group_name")
{
    std::vector<glm::vec3> out_vertices;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> out_normals;
    std::vector<glm::ivec3> out_triangles;
    // std::cout << ("Hi\n");
    //  opengl_triangulation::triangulate_flat_polylines_with_holes(in_polylines, out_vertices, out_normals, out_triangles);
    opengl_triangulation::triangulate_flat_polylines(in_polylines, out_vertices, out_normals, out_triangles, convex_only, closed_tolerance);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    std::vector<std::vector<glm::vec3>> vertices;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> one_face = {glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), glm::vec3(1, 0, 0), glm::vec3(1, 1, 0), glm::vec3(0, 0, 0)};
    vertices.emplace_back(one_face);
    add(vertices, glm::vec4(0, 0, 0, 0), false, 0.001f, 1.0f, "mesh_outlines_wood");

    return 0;
}
```

opengl_triangulation.h

```
#pragma once
//#include "../../../stdafx.h"
//#include <cdt/CDT.h>
// CDT

namespace opengl_triangulation
{
    inline void triangulate_flat_polyline_with_holes(
        const std::vector<std::vector<glm::vec3>> &in_polylines,
        std::vector<glm::vec3> &out_vertices,
        std::vector<glm::vec3> &out_normals,
        std::vector<glm::ivec3> &out_triangles,
        bool convex_only = false, double closed_tolerance = 0.001)
    {

        // v.insert(v.end(), v_prime.begin(), v_prime.end());
        // std::vector<std::vector<glm::vec3>> input_normals;
        // input_normals.reserve(in_polylines.size());

        glm::vec3 v(0, 0, 0);

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // is closed and number of vertices in the last iteration
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        std::vector<bool> closed_ends;
        closed_ends.reserve(in_polylines.size());
        int all_v_count = 0;
        int all_v_count_start = out_vertices.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < in_polylines.size(); i++)
        {
            closed_ends.emplace_back(glm::distance(in_polylines[i].front(), in_polylines[i].back()) < closed_tolerance);

            size_t len = closed_ends.back() ? in_polylines[i].size() - 1 : in_polylines[i].size();
            all_v_count += len;
            // print(glm::distance(in_polylines[i].front(), in_polylines[i].back()));
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // get transformation matrices
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        glm::mat4 to_xy;
        glm::mat4 to_3d;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            size_t len = closed_ends[i] ? in_polylines[i].size() - 1 : in_polylines[i].size();

            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
            {
                auto num = ((j - 1) + len) % len;
                auto item1 = ((j + 1) + len) % len;
                v = v + glm::cross(in_polylines[i][j] - in_polylines[i][num], in_polylines[i][item1] - in_polylines[i][j]);
            }
            v = glm::normalize(v);

            // x-axis
            float length = hypotf(v.x, hypotf(v.y, v.z));
            float dir_scalar = (v.x > 0.0) ? length : -length;
            float xt = v.x + dir_scalar;
            float dot = -v.y / (dir_scalar * xt);

            glm::vec3 x = glm::vec3(dot * xt, 1.0f + dot * v.y, dot * v.z);
            x = glm::normalize(x);
            // y-axis
            glm::vec3 y = glm::cross(v, x);

            glm::vec3 o = glm::vec3(in_polylines[i][0].x, in_polylines[i][0].y, in_polylines[i][0].z);
            // print(o.x, o.y, o.z);
            // print(x.x, x.y, x.z);
            // print(y.x, y.y, y.z);
            // print(v.x, v.y, v.z);
            // print("next");

            // to_xy = (opengl_transform::plane_to_plane(
            //     o.x, o.y, o.z,
            //     x.x, x.y, x.z,
            //     y.x, y.y, y.z,
            //     v.x, v.y, v.z,
            //     0, 0, 0,
            //     1, 0, 0,
            //     0, 1, 0,
            //     0, 0, 1));
            // to_3d = (opengl_transform::plane_to_plane(
            //     0, 0, 0,
            //     1, 0, 0,
            //     0, 1, 0,
            //     0, 0, 1,
            //     o.x, o.y, o.z,
            //     x.x, x.y, x.z,
            //     y.x, y.y, y.z,
            //     v.x, v.y, v.z

            //     ));
        }

        out_normals.reserve(out_normals.size() + all_v_count);
        out_vertices.reserve(out_vertices.size() + all_v_count);

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // cdt https://github.com/artem-ogre/CDT/issues/73
        // rules: order and orientation of curves does not matter
        // polylines are treated as open
        // code orients polylines to 2d and then orients back to 3D
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        CDT::Triangulation<float> cdt;

        // vertices
        std::vector<CDT::V2d<float>> cdt_vertices;
        int total_count_of_v = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < in_polylines.size(); i++)
        {
            int is_closed = (glm::distance(in_polylines[i].front(), in_polylines[i].back()) < 0.01) ? -1 : 0;
            total_count_of_v += (int)in_polylines.size() + is_closed;
        }
        cdt_vertices.reserve(total_count_of_v);

        // print("normal");
        // print(v.x, v.y, v.z);
        for (int i = 0; i < in_polylines.size(); i++)
        {
            size_t is_closed = (glm::distance(in_polylines[i].front(), in_polylines[i].back()) < 0.01) ? -1 : 0;
            // std::vector<glm::vec3> norm;
            // norm.reserve(in_polylines[i].size() + is_closed);
            for (int j = 0; j < in_polylines[i].size() + is_closed; j++)
            {
                // transformation to xy
                out_vertices.emplace_back(in_polylines[i][j]);
                out_normals.emplace_back(v);
                auto p4 = glm::vec4(in_polylines[i][j].x, in_polylines[i][j].y, in_polylines[i][j].z, 1);
                auto p = glm::vec3(p4.x, p4.y, p4.z);
                // print(p.x, p.y, p.z);
                // auto p = glm::vec3(in_polylines[i][j].x, in_polylines[i][j].y, in_polylines[i][j].z);
                cdt_vertices.emplace_back(CDT::V2d<float>::make(p.x, p.y));
            }
            // input_normals.emplace_back(norm);
        }

        //{ CDT::V2d<float>::make(15,-7),CDT::V2d<float>::make(9.62180016727275f,4.57060284363674f),CDT::V2d<float>::make(12,4.43070873582926f),CDT::V2d<float>::make(19,0),CDT::V2d<float>::make(16,-5),CDT::V2d<float>::make(6,-16),CDT::V2d<float>::make(15,-9),CDT::V2d<float>::make(22,-22),CDT::V2d<float>::make(22,2),CDT::V2d<float>::make(7,11),CDT::V2d<float>::make(6,-6),CDT::V2d<float>::make(-7,-2),CDT::V2d<float>::make(-15,16),CDT::V2d<float>::make(-17,23),CDT::V2d<float>::make(-43,28),CDT::V2d<float>::make(-24,-10),CDT::V2d<float>::make(-17,-11),CDT::V2d<float>::make(-23,8),CDT::V2d<float>::make(-14,2),CDT::V2d<float>::make(7,-33),CDT::V2d<float>::make(-3,-11),CDT::V2d<float>::make(-15,7),CDT::V2d<float>::make(-19,16),CDT::V2d<float>::make(-23,18),CDT::V2d<float>::make(-31,21),CDT::V2d<float>::make(-28,8),CDT::V2d<float>::make(-27,6),CDT::V2d<float>::make(-25,10),CDT::V2d<float>::make(-25,17) }
        //;
        cdt.insertVertices(cdt_vertices);

        // edges
        if (!convex_only)
        {
            std::vector<CDT::Edge> edges; // CDT::EdgeVec edges;
            std::vector<int> edge_per_polyline;
            edge_per_polyline.reserve(in_polylines.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < in_polylines.size(); i++)
            {
                int is_closed = (glm::distance(in_polylines[i].front(), in_polylines[i].back()) < 0.01) ? -1 : 0;
                edge_per_polyline.emplace_back(in_polylines[i].size() + is_closed);
            }

            int total_count_of_e = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < edge_per_polyline.size(); i++)
                total_count_of_e += edge_per_polyline[i];
            edges.reserve(total_count_of_e);

            int v_count = 0;
            int group_count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < edge_per_polyline.size(); i++)
            {
                group_count += edge_per_polyline[i];

                int start = v_count;
                for (int j = 0; j < edge_per_polyline[i] - 1; j++)
                {
                    edges.emplace_back(CDT::Edge(v_count, v_count + 1));
                    // print(v_count, v_count + 1);
                    v_count++;
                }
                edges.emplace_back(CDT::Edge(v_count, start));
                // print(v_count, start);
                // print("next");
                v_count++;
            }
            cdt.insertEdges(edges);

            cdt.eraseOuterTrianglesAndHoles();
        }
        else
        {
            cdt.eraseSuperTriangle();
        }

        auto out_triangles_size = out_triangles.size() + cdt.triangles.size() * 3;
        out_triangles.reserve(out_triangles_size);
        // print("next");
        // print(all_v_count_start);
        // print(all_v_count);
        for (int i = 0; i < cdt.triangles.size(); i++)
        {
            // print(all_v_count_start + cdt.triangles[i].vertices[0], all_v_count_start + cdt.triangles[i].vertices[1], all_v_count_start + cdt.triangles[i].vertices[2]);
            out_triangles.emplace_back(
                all_v_count_start + cdt.triangles[i].vertices[0],
                all_v_count_start + cdt.triangles[i].vertices[1],
                all_v_count_start + cdt.triangles[i].vertices[2]);
        }
    }

    inline void triangulate_flat_polylines(
        const std::vector<std::vector<glm::vec3>> &in_polylines,
        std::vector<glm::vec3> &out_vertices,
        std::vector<glm::vec3> &out_normals,
        std::vector<glm::ivec3> &out_triangles,
        bool convex_only = false, double closed_tolerance = 0.001

    )
    {
        // std::cout << ("\ntriangulaiton\n");
        for (auto &in_polyline : in_polylines)
        {
            triangulate_flat_polyline_with_holes(
                {in_polyline},
                out_vertices,
                out_normals,
                out_triangles, convex_only, closed_tolerance);
        }
    }

    inline void triangulate_flat_polylines_with_holes(
        const std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<glm::vec3>>> &in_polylines_groups,
        std::vector<glm::vec3> &out_vertices,
        std::vector<glm::vec3> &out_normals,
        std::vector<glm::ivec3> &out_triangles,
        bool convex_only = false, double closed_tolerance = 0.001

    )
    {
        for (auto &in_polylines : in_polylines_groups)
            triangulate_flat_polyline_with_holes(
                in_polylines,
                out_vertices,
                out_normals,
                out_triangles, convex_only, closed_tolerance);
    }
}
```

Error

```
  Checking Build System
main.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::vector
<unsigned short,class std::allocator<unsigne 
d short> > __cdecl CDT::CalculateTriangleDep 
ths(unsigned int,class std::vector<struct CD 
T::Triangle,class std::allocator<struct CDT: 
:Triangle> > const &,class std::unordered_se
t<struct CDT::Edge,struct std::hash<struct C 
DT::Edge>,struct std::equal_to<struct CDT::E 
dge>,class std::allocator<struct CDT::Edge>  
> const &,class std::unordered_map<struct CD 
T::Edge,unsigned short,struct std::hash<stru 
ct CDT::Edge>,struct std::equal_to<struct CD 
T::Edge>,class std::allocator<struct std::pa 
ir<struct CDT::Edge const ,unsigned short> > 
 > const &)" (?CalculateTriangleDepths@CDT@@ 
YA?AV?$vector@GV?$allocator@G@std@@@std@@IAE 
BV?$vector@UTriangle@CDT@@V?$allocator@UTria 
ngle@CDT@@@std@@@3@AEBV?$unordered_set@UEdge 
@CDT@@U?$hash@UEdge@CDT@@@std@@U?$equal_to@U 
Edge@CDT@@@4@V?$allocator@UEdge@CDT@@@4@@3@A 
EBV?$unordered_map@UEdge@CDT@@GU?$hash@UEdge 
@CDT@@@std@@U?$equal_to@UEdge@CDT@@@4@V?$all 
ocator@U?$pair@$$CBUEdge@CDT@@G@std@@@4@@3@@ 
Z) already defined in cmake_pch.obj [C:\IBOI 
S57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\com 
pas_wood\cdt_test\build\cdt_test.vcxproj]    
C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_bu
ild\compas_wood\cdt_test\build\Release\cdt_t 
est.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more m 
ultiply defined symbols found [C:\IBOIS57\_C 
ode\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wo 
od\cdt_test\build\cdt_test.vcxproj]
```

Comment: You might need to re-generate your pre-compiled headers, or stop using precompiled headers altogether in the project. I usually prefer it without them.

Comment: @wohlstad since I am trying to solve this problem for a couple of long days... I already tried to do that. I also created a new project and configured everything from scratch...

Comment: I added at the end of the question.

Comment: This example is nowhere close to [mcve]

Comment: "Since Stackoverflow is against the 3rd party links I will share the full code below.". Eh, no. That's also not the intention. Create a **minimal** example. This is way, way too much.

Answer (score 0):

The question was answered here:
https://github.com/artem-ogre/CDT/issues/105